# Hadoop Reducer provides an writable values.Next() returns?

Tags: hadoop

In the reducer, the MapReduce API provides you with an iterator over Writable values. Calling the next() method:
A. Returns a reference to a different Writable object each time.
B. Returns a reference to a Writable object from an object pool.
C. Returns a reference to the same writable object each time, but populated with different data.
D. Returns a reference to a Writable object. The API leaves unspecified whether this is a reused object or a new object.
E. Returns a reference to the same writable object if the next value is the same as the previous value, or a new writable object otherwise.

Comment: Is this a certification question?

Comment: @ Thomas Jungblut: A. Not sure what you mean by certification question B. there are 5 choices C. The "voice" of the text changes once the options begin. D. I still know the answer E. Joe K beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is C. It does this to save the overhead of instantiating a new object for every key.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: 
**C**. Returns a reference to the same writable object each time, but populated with different data.

A reducer is known to group all the values of a corresponding key with the Iterator or the Iterable. E.g. in the reduce() method:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws Exception{

//Code here

// for iterating through the values

    while(values.hasNext()){
               //code here

    }

}
```

Here, values is the same Writable object (Text) which is populated with different data each time it iterates.